# How to copy recently added files to an external hard drive with a script

Tags: windows, shell, copy

Wondering if you could help!

I add files to my external hard drive every other week and I was wondering if there was a script I could write/set up to automatically run every time I added something new to the folders within my external hard drive and to copy them into a recently added folder.

eg

files all ready on the hard drive

then added 4 files on the 1/02/14

then added 2 files on the 8/02/14

I would only want the February files (or the last so many files) to be copied into the recently added folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

use xcopy `<source> <destination> /D`

> /D:mm-dd-yyyy
>                   Copy files changed on or after the specified date.
>                   If no date is given, copy only files whose
>                   source date/time is newer than the destination time.